# Orion Constellation request

Tags: amateur-observing, observational-astronomy, photography, orion

This isn't a question so much as a request. I'm looking for an image of the Orion constalletion I could use, but I would like to have a very high resolution HD image, whereby a lot of the deep sky objects can be seen to high detail other than just the 7 hourglass stars of the belt and four corners. Would love to have perhaps the Orion nebula (Messier 42), the Horsehead Nebula (near ζ Orionis), the emission nebula NGC 2174, Messier 43 and Barnard's Loop.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're looking for images, not charts, correct?

Comment: @Ricky Not me, personally, but there are many star/deepsky catalogs that can help visualize a constellation, even if they're not actually pictures.

Answer (score 2):

The [Astronomy Picture of the day for the 23rd November 2015](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap151123.html) has all the neblosity around Orion, in fantatic detail. The result of 212 hour exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Install either Stellarium or Cartes du Ciel, drag the sky chart around, zoom in or out, frame the constellation any way you like, then take a screenshot.

http://www.stellarium.org/

http://www.ap-i.net/skychart/en/start

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want it for is all important?

I use World Wide Telescope (http://www.worldwidetelescope.org) as a demonstration tool.

You can use it to look at any part of the sky using a variety of catalogues and imagery. The default "background" imagery is from the digitised sky survey.

The way it works is that if you zoom into an area it downloads higher and higher resolution images, but you can cache these. Thus you can scan and cache the whole of Orion so that you can pan and zoom (particularly effective with a mouse wheel) rapidly and at will at a later date.

You can also supplement the DSS images with (e.g. HST images of the Orion Nebula cluster), which are overlaid and rotated correctly onto the DSS image.

If you have an HD display, then of course you can take a screenshot of any view you arrange.